# How to stretch compoiste layout in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I created an application with two parts :

```
      1. tree viewer
      2. table viewer + messages
```

it look like

```
                 -------------------------------
                 -   tree    -         table   -   
                 -           -                 -
                 -           - -----------------             
                 -           -                 -
                 -           -   messages      -       
                 -------------------------------
```

The problem that the right part ( table and message doesn't stretch until the end like the first part )

it look like

```
                  -------------------------------
                 -   tree    -         table   -   
                 -           -  -----------------               -
                 -           -                  -
                                 meesages       -    
                 -           --------------------  
                 -           -              
                 -------------
```

This is the code

```
     SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(parent, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    Composite treeComposite = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.BORDER);
    Composite detailsCompositePart = new Composite(sashForm, SWT.NONE);

    GridLayout detailsGridLayout = new GridLayout();
    detailsGridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    detailsCompositePart.setLayout(detailsGridLayout);

    GridData detailsPartGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    detailsCompositePart.setLayoutData(detailsPartGridData);

    detailsComposite = new Composite(detailsCompositePart, SWT.BORDER);
    GridLayout detailsSideGridLayout = new GridLayout();
    detailsSideGridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    detailsComposite.setLayout(detailsSideGridLayout);
    GridData detailsGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    detailsComposite.setLayoutData(detailsGridData);

     messageComposite = new Composite(detailsComposite, SWT.NONE);

     GridLayout messageGridLayout = new GridLayout();
     messageGridLayout.numColumns = 1;
     messageComposite.setLayout(messageGridLayout);
     GridData messageGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, false);
     messageComposite.setLayoutData(messageGridData);



    labelError = new Label(messageGridData , SWT.NONE);
    GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.END, true, false);
    data.heightHint = 30;
    labelError.setLayoutData(data);
    //labelError.setText("Message!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your complete code, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Here is some code that should help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    Composite horizontal = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    horizontal.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    horizontal.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Composite left = new Composite(horizontal, SWT.BORDER);
    left.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Composite right = new Composite(horizontal, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    layout.marginWidth = 0;
    right.setLayout(layout);
    right.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Composite top = new Composite(right, SWT.BORDER);
    top.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Composite bottom = new Composite(right, SWT.BORDER);
    bottom.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(600, 400);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

If that's not what you are looking for, please update your question with more details/code.

Comment: but I added ridData detailsGridData = new GridData();
    detailsGridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    detailsGridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    detailsGridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    detailsGridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    detailsComposite.setLayoutData(detailsGridData);

Comment: @user1365697 Sure, updated the answer. Looks the same.

Comment: Hi Baz could we have a chat ?

Comment: I updated my code in general the right screen that split to tree and message have two different composite( they have the same parent ).The issue that I don't see any message in the layout and the size of the layout is not the same as the left screen.I want the table will catch almost all the screen and the message could only one line

Comment: @user1365697 I posted some code for you in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42990/baz-and-user1365697).

Comment: @user1365697 Please consider accepting this answer, since your issue seems to be resolved.